# About 18650 batteries possible accidents with reversed polarity

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium, reverse-polarity

We all know that lithium batteries are dangerous and can blow up if we use them the wrong way. My doubt is, if I accidentally place them in the following sequence in series (Pay attention to the polarity):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGh0oL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can I end up blowing up one of them?

Comment: One acts as a load and will be charged by the others. Given they require special charging curves it certainly wont do anything good! (also, please use the schematic tool to make an easier to read drawing).

Comment: Didn't know there was a schematic tool, lol, thanks

Comment: Chances of the battery blowing up is pretty low with just a voltmeter connected.

Answer (score 1):

With just the voltmeter connected as shown, no, nothing should blow up.  This is assuming a typical voltmeter with 10 MΩ or so input resistance.

However, if you connect this battery string to a real load, then bad things could happen to BAT3.  Think of the limiting case where the load is a short circuit.  Now you have three batteries trying to charge one.  That's not going to end well.  Assuming all batteries start out well charged, BAT3 will be rapidly overcharged.  It could leak, blow up, catch fire, or the like.

This may not be good for the other three batteries either.  You basically have two cells driving the internal resistance of four cells.  That could result in excessive discharge current, which could also cause BAT1, BAT2, and BAT4 to exhibit "unfortunate" behavior.

Comment: I used the Voltmeter as an example, let's say instead a voltmeter, we have a circuit draining 400mAH and the total current of the batteries is 3000mAH.